# adding css style to selected input fields using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I set css style on page load to certain input boxes using jquery something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input, textarea").addClass("idle");
    $("input, textarea").focus(function() {
        $(this).addClass("activeField").removeClass("idle");
    }).blur(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("activeField").addClass("idle");
    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<input type="text" name="author" id="author" >
<input type="text" name=email id=email >
```

But this will add the style to each and every input and textarea which I want to avoid.

How can I apply the desired style to selective inputs/text area fields?

Comment: You can target them by name or id. Can you post the HTML?

Comment: show the html and what you want to select, also look at jquery selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify the inputs by id or class. In your example, you could apply your classes to the author textbox only by doing:

```
$("#author").addClass("idle");
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to add something unique to each input and textarea that you want to apply your function. You could use `class` for example. So, give every textarea and input that you want to select the same class name, like `class="switchCSS"`. Then you can apply your jquery like this:

```
$("input.switchCSS, textarea.switchCSS").addClass("idle");
//etc etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using only CSS to do this, instead of making two different classes you should make one class and a pseudo-class.

```
input, textarea{
    ...
}

input:focus, textarea:focus{
    ...
}
```

I created a quick example to show this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gp8Rr/1/

In case you want only one (or certain) input elements to have this, you should create a specific class in css and a pseudo class, and just assign those classes in your html.

CSS:

```
.styled{
    ...
}

.style:focus{
    ...
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="author" id="author" class="switch">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email">
```

Another quick example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/Apd6V/

Comment: He wants the CSS applied to specific elements, not just when they're being hovered over.

Comment: @j08691 then he should create a specific class and assign it to the input element he wants to have this class on. I'll edit my answer right away.